# Converting vector arrays into .MPS files with C++

Tags: c++, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, coin-or-cbc

I'm trying to use Coin-OR's linear-programming (LP) software to solve a series of linear programs.  Most of the data for each program is contained in a couple of .csv files, but some of the data needs to be revised every time I run the linear optimization.

It looks like I can only ask Coin-OR's LP solver to read .MPS files, and it's possible to build a .MPS file separately using a program like AMPL.  But given that I'm trying to run an automated, iterated series of these optimizations, it's not feasible just to build a single problem instance with AMPL or Gurobi and then call the solver on the resulting .MPS file; I need the file to change with every problem, possibly thousands or millions of times.

So does anyone know if there's a C++ library that can convert vector arrays or other standard C++ data structures into .MPS files?  Alternatively, is there a way that I can specify these data structures as inputs for Coin-OR's LP solver?

Comment: I think only the "Alternatively" part of this question is on-topic. As per the flags, "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 2):

Is it not better to call Coin-OR's CLP via its API? For pure LPs writing and reading MPS files can become expensive. Otherwise CLP has its own MPSWriter you can borrow: CoinMpsIO::writeMps. If you run many similar models you may want to make sure to warm-start the solver. Also AMPL has a direct COIN-OR CLP interface (https://github.com/ampl/coin) so no need to go through an MPS file.

Comment: Is there a C / C++ example online to demonstrate how a LP can be built in memory and then solved with a call to CLP?

Comment: In the examples directory is a demo how to use `loadproblem`:  [link](https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp/browser/trunk/Clp/examples/network.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

As Erwin said. Use the API. Using MPS files or similar is useful for trying a given model on different solvers. The LP format is good for understanding whether your model implements what you expected. Maybe even use MPS files for archiving specific cases for regression testing or similar. But NOBODY should be creating files to be fed to a solver. If at all possible, use an API.